# graphics-card makes sound-card produce a buzzing sound

Tags: graphics-card, audio, sound-card, noise

Recently I bought a new GPU: GeForce GTX 550 Ti, and after installing it I get a strange buzzing sound. It's not always there, just sometimes (mostly when I open some game, but sometimes also in browsers etc.).

It's not a capacitor or a fan, as unplugging speakers from sound-card makes the 'bzzzzzzz' go away. However, muting windows doesn't mute this sound.

I'm pretty sure it is fault of the new GPU, but how is this happening and can I fix it?

Can it be a low power supply? I thought of buying a stronger unit, but as everything works, and computer doesn't shut down, I hesitate.

Comment: I don't think it is the graphic cards fault. I think your speakers are not well protected from induced high frequencies. Do you have the same problem if your mobile phone is too close to your speakers when someone calls?

Comment: Check how the power cables for the Graphics Card are routed.  Are they near/touching your sound card?  If this happened only after installing the new card, my bet would be that the induction is happening inside your tower.

Comment: Another thing to try is to plug the computer into a different outlet, in case it might be a grounding problem.

Comment: @WalterMaier-Murdnelch, my speakers are inside my monitor, but I checked it with my headphones and they get the sound as well. Also I never heard a characteristic mobile call sound on my speakers, so I don't think that's it.

Comment: @Josh: my sound-card is built in my motherboard. There were some cables to front sockets, above a graphics-card's fan, but unplugging them gave me nothing. Maybe it's the power cables interfering? This card is taking more power and has an additional cable to it's fan. @ Bryce: I still need to check other power sources, but I hadn't this problem with the old card. @ everyone: maybe it's a software problem? I found out there were 4 (repeated) Nvidia High Definition Audio in my devices. I turned them off but again no change. Maybe I should look for it in BIOS?